# Hibernate list distinct from 4 tables

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

We are rewritting some legacy code from sql to gorm with hibernate.
I've stumbled upon a problem - we have 4 different tables, mapped to 4 domain classes. Each of them has one column/attribute named the same.
Consider following (*actually pretty stupid*) tables for simplification:

```
+-------------------+      +---------------------------+
| id | name |  role |      | id | position |    role   |
+-------------------+      +---------------------------+
|  1 | John | admin |      |  1 |  manager |     admin |
|  2 |  Bob |  user |      |  2 | sysadmin | superuser |
+-------------------+      +---------------------------+
```

From these tables/classes, I need to extract all *distinct* roles.
With SQL, this can be easily done with union:

```
SELECT role FROM Table1 UNION SELECT role FROM Table2 GROUP BY role
```

which returns desired result: [admin, user, superuser]

Now I wonder, how can this be done with gorm/hibernate. One possible solution would be using two criterias as followed:

```
first = Table1.createCriteria().list {
  projections {
    distinct "role"
  }
}
second = Table2.createCriteria().list {
  projections {
    distinct "role"
  }
}
```

then going through them and filtering duplicates. However this is not very efficient and takes almost twice the time of the original query (given 4 tables, effectively resulting in 4 queries). 
So, what is the most efficient (time & resources) solution for this?

// UPDATE (in response to @Emmanuel)

I am not in control of the database. My access is read-only. To make it even more dreadful, there is approximately 4 million rows in the tables, combined. Those data get regularly updated and new rows are added every minute, making it impossible to create new table somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GORM/Hibernate does not support UNION queries. What I recommend is to normalize the tables so that the column (ex. roles) is in a single table and the others refer to it via foreign keys. Using your table examples:

```
+-----------------+
+ id | role       +
+-----------------+
+  1 | admin      +
+  2 | user       +
+  3 | superuser  +
+-----------------+

+-------------------+
+ id | name |  role +
+-------------------+
+  1 | John |   1   +
+  2 |  Bob |   2   +
+-------------------+

+---------------------------+
+ id | position |    role   +
+---------------------------+
+  1 |  manager |     1     +
+  2 | sysadmin |     3     +
+---------------------------+
```

Then, of course, you'd be able to simply query the new domain class.

Comment: Well, I'd say you're between a rock and a hard place. GORM is not going to be of any assistance. But, it does provide a way to get a Hibernate session, which means you can execute SQL: `def roles = AnyDomainClassReallyAnyWillDo.withNewSession { session -> session.createSQLQuery('SELECT role FROM Table1 UNION SELECT role FROM Table2 GROUP BY role').list() }`

Comment: When I went here to ask, deep down I knew this would be the only solution. However, a bit of hope still remains - I will wait some time for other suggestions. If there isnt't anything else, I'll accept this as an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use HQL, you could do this:

```
List<Role> list = Table1.createCriteria().list {
  projections {
    distinct "role"
    property "role"
  }
}
list = Table2.createCriteria().list {
  not{
    'in'('role', list)
  }
  projections {
    distinct "role"
    property "role"
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work, I've already tried something along those lines. The `list` gets way too big after 2nd query and then the 3rd one fails - there is a limit, 1k or 10k or something like that for list filters

Comment: Oh yes sorry, you have to collect only the property role. Try the correction.

Comment: You don't understand. The problem is in `'in'('role', list)` which fails if `list` is too big, which in my case is.

Comment: The first criteria gives you only the unique roles which your Table1 has.